# How to ignore the first line in a csv file when you read the csv file in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I now how to read a csv file in C#. For instance, the file data consists of three columns, you can make an array that has three columns and the number of rows does not matter since you can use, for instance a while loop that read the csv file until it gets null.

I just want to know how not to read the first line of a csv file and read the rest of it. Sometimes data files such as .txt, .csv contains different types of data. In a csv file, it might have "store catalog" in the first line as the title and then have a phone number, a owner name, a monthly sale in each line from the second line.

Comment: If you've got a working CSV reader, just read the first line and throw it away.

Comment: what is your current code ? but basically what @RobertHarvey said is what you need to do

Answer (score 2):

It's going to end up looking something like.

```
reader.ReadLine();

var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

or you could do something like:

```
var text = reader.ReadAllLines();
text = text.Skip(1);
```

This is all assuming you're using the built-in .NET readers, of course.

Answer (score 1):

One way, use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) and [`Enumerable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> allButFirstLine = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1);
```

If you want to know the difference between `ReadAllLines` and `ReadLines` read the [remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) section.

If you are using a `StreamReader`, use `ReadLine()` and do nothing:

```
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(path, encoding))
{
    // change numToSkip accordingly
    for (int i = 0; i < numToSkip; i++) 
        reader.ReadLine();  

    // ...
```